# How to use datePicker in <aui:form> in liferay6.2

Tags: liferay-6.2

I am beginner to Liferay.
I want to know how to use datePicker in  in Liferay6.2.

Thanks and regard:
Manoj Kumar.

Answer (score -1):

refer the below link for datepicker

[source](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14871486)